# Arduino. Как передать пьезоэлементу высокую частоту?

Tags: c++, arduino

Основная суть моего проекта - распыление воды. В интернете я вычитал, что для этого можно использовать ультразвуковой распылитель или же обычный пьезоэлемент, который издавая ультразвук будет распылять воду. Сам распылитель содержит два провода(плюс, минус). Но как передать высокую частоту через ардуино? Возможно ли это? Я пытался сделать это обычным analogWrite();

Comment: а пробовали в цикле писать 0-1-0-1 и так далее

Comment: @KoVadim нет, не пробовал

Comment: но лучше почитайте ответ @gbg, он хорошо пишет

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы фокус сработал, нужно подавать на пьезу синус, причем не просто высокой (135 kHz), а резонансной частоты, которая является индивидуальной для каждого излучателя. Это можно сделать аналоговой схемой на 555.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Оригинал](https://www.instructables.com/DIY-MISTFOG-MAKER-USING-IC-555/)

Вместо 555 сюда можно запихать микроконтроллер (оставив LC-фильтр, который превратит прямоугольник в синус), но тогда в нем нужно будет предусмотреть также тонкую подстройку частоты, чтобы поймать резонанс.

Если разрезать картинку вертикально пополам, у нас слева будет генератор, а справа - согласование с излучателем. Генератор должен выдавать прямоугльник от 0 до 15 вольт амплитудой, а ардуина может выдать от 0 до 5 вольт. Следовательно, потребуется после ардуины поставить мелкий PNP-транзистор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

который раскачает выходящий из нее сигнал до 15 вольт, после чего загнать его уже в MOSFET, который будет раскачивать пьезу.

Comment: Справа "High Side" плохой вариант, так лучше не делать.

Comment: @ГеннадийП - так я и написал в ответе, что нужно брать левый вариант.

Comment: Небольшая поправка: «амплитуда генератора» может быть любой, достаточной чтобы открыть мосфет. 5 В для большинства (в частности для указанного irf z44) вполне хватит… Дополнительный каскад с транзистором нужен потому что микроконтроллер не может обеспечить достаточный ток (ограничиваемый `R2`). А если увеличить `R2` до `1k`, то это может привести к значительному завалу фронтов и вместо трапеции получится пила или  упадёт скважность (я не считал, действительно ли так получится)…

Comment: И даже для 555'го указанное сопротивление ИМХО маловато: я бы увеличил его до 75 Ом, дабы ограничить ток до штатных 200 мА (хотя как сильно это повлияет на форму сигнала я тоже не считал)… ЗЫ: мои знания в электронике крайне поверхностны, так что всё что я написал выше может не соответствовать действительности…

Comment: @Fat-Zer - если посмотреть в даташите на зависимость между напряжением затвор-исток и обеспечивыемым выходным током (Fig3), при 5 вольтах будет печка, а не транзистор уже на токе около ампера. А вот с типом транзистора раскачки я промахнулся - PNP конечно же. Исправил пост.

Comment: @gbg, наверно ты прав... я правильно читаю, что эквивалентное сопротивление канала DS при V_GS=5V будет 25/20≈1,25 Ом? а как в этой схеме рассчитать средний ток через транзистор (чтобы получить мощность)?

Comment: @Fat-Zer - если грубо, нужно умножить DutyCycle в процентах на мощность, которая получается, когда транзистор открыт - у нас же прямоугольник.

Comment: @gbg, дык, на сколько я понимаю, ток через транзистор будет не линейным и будет зависеть от частоты, индуктивности L1, ёмкости C3 и, возможно параметров пьезы, так что «мощность, которая получается, когда транзистор открыт» будет не линейной, или не так?

Comment: Я же написал - "грубо". Чтобы точно посчитать, нужно прогнать моделирование.

Comment: @gbg, а как хотя бы грубо посчитать ток/мощность на транзисторе с помощью этого? если считать, что индуктивности в принципе нет и транзистор замкнут на источник напряжения, то тогда получается, что чем больше напряжение на затворе, тем больше будет выделяться на нём мощность: при V_GS=15В это получается `100—200А*15В` ≈ `1,5—3кВт`, а при V_GS=5В будет `~10—20А*15В` ≈ `0,15—0,30кВт`. Понятно, что числовые значения абсурдно велики и деление на 2 тут особой погоды не сделает. Собственно как это хотя бы прикинуть? или только симуляция?

Comment: ЗЫ: И я понимаю, что уже достаточно сильно ушёл в оффтоп для обсуждения в комментариях, но ничего не могу с собой поделать — меня просто заинтересовала тема…

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133306/discussion-between-gbg-and-fat-zer).

Comment: @gbg я пришел домой, а тут открыта эта вкладка... дома только кошка и я начинаю что-то подозревать.... а про теме  с бытового контроллера сложно получить высокую частоту.

Comment: @eri - как же тогда здесь получили 8 MHz с обычной атмеги?

Comment: Здесь - это вот http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/signalgen/rectgen_m8.html

Comment: http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/signalgen/rectgen_m8_v1_main.html - асемблер.... я же говорил сложно, а не невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

analogWrite нормально работает низкой частоте. до 10 кГц на современных чипах. на ардуинах хорошо если вытянешь полтора кГц. 125 кГц  можно вытянуть на шине sclk, но в резонанс это не попадет.

резать схему @gbg не нужно, подключите микроконтроллер к генератору:

4 нога (ресет) на микроконтроллер с открытым колектором через резистор 1k
её же через 10k к плюсу питания